# Gorm Criteria for "each in" / "none in"

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, criteria

I have to write some queries to implement a search in a complex data model. I want to use the Criteria DSL of Gorm to solve that.
For simple queries like the examples in the [Gorm](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html) or [Grails Documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.9/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) it's no problem, but I don't know, how to implement more complicated queries like 
"each in", "none in" or "only one of x is in". I hope someone can give me a hint.

---

Grails Domain Classes:

```
class Content {
    Integer contentNumber
    static hasMany = [titles : Title]
}

class Title {
    String title
    Titletype titletype
}

class Titletype {
    String name
}
```

Method with Criteria:

```
def filter(GrailsParameterMap args) {

    //To ensure that the ids of titletypes to query are always given as Long[]
    Long[] argsTitletype = [args.title.titletype.value].flatten() as Long[]

    def query = new DetachedCriteria(Content).build {}

        // Every Content, which has a Title with Titletype in argsTitletype
        query = query.build {
                    titles {
                        'in'('titletype.id', argsTitletype)
                    }
                }

        return query.list()
    }
```

The return of the query above has the expected result: All Content, which has a Titletype in argsTitletype

---

But how to query "Content, which has **all** the Titletypes in argsTitletype"?
I tried for example:

```
query = query.build {
               titles {
                   and {
                       argsTitletype.each { tt -> 
                           eq('titletype.id', tt)
                       }
                   }      
                }
```

or

```
query = query.build {
               and {
                     argsTitletype.each { tt -> 
                       titles {
                           eq('titletype.id', tt)
                       }
                   }      
                }
```

Where is my misstake? Have I to use Subqueries?

Answer (score 0):

For your **all-in** Try the following out:

```
query = query.build {
               titles {
                   titletype {
                     argsTitletype.each { tt ->                        
                           eq 'id', tt
                     }
                   }      
                }
              }
```

you don't need `and`s here, as those are applied by default.

Comment: That works only for one titletype.id. If I query with `argsTitletype = [1]` I get all `Content` with `titletype.id == 1`. But if I provide more than one argument such as `argsTitletype = [1, 2]` I get an empty result. (I know there is an `Content`, which has  a `Titletype` with `id=1` and another with `id=2`)

Comment: set `dataSource.logSql` to `true` in your configuration and analyze the query

Comment: try swapping the lines `titles{` and `argsTitletype.each { tt ->`

Comment: I tried that. It doesnt work either. I think     it's necessary to work with sub
queries and "exists". But for now I will use SQL.

Comment: yeah, that kind of all-in mandatory intersection is not something out-of-box provided by SQL, you have to apply some dirty tricks